# alsa driver compiled with errors 12.04.02 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, alsa

I have a problem with installing the alsa driver.

Here is the compilation log:

```
In file included from /home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire/speakers.c:5:0:
/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire/../alsa-kernel/firewire/speakers.c: В функции «fwspk_card_free»:
/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire/../alsa-kernel/firewire/speakers.c:664:2: ошибка: неявная декларация функции «fw_device_put» [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire/../alsa-kernel/firewire/speakers.c: В функции «fwspk_probe»:
/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire/../alsa-kernel/firewire/speakers.c:721:2: ошибка: неявная декларация функции «fw_device_get» [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire/speakers.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** [/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25/firewire] Ошибка 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/aleks/alsa-driver-1.0.25] Ошибка 2
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic'
make: *** [compile] Ошибка 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1.0.25 driver package is outdated.

The drivers are part of kernel; to update the drivers, just [update the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).